# flow decomposition theorem in networks

Tags: algorithm

I am reading algorithms volume 2 by Robert Sedgewick. This section is from Network flow algorithms.

I am having a difficulty in understanding flow decompostion theorem and its corollaries which are mentioned below.

Flow decomposition theorem: Any circulation can be represented as flow along a set of at most E directed edges.

Corollary 1: Any st-network has a maxflow such that the subgraph induced by nonzeroflow values is acyclic.

Corollary 2: Any st-network has a maxflow that can be represented as flow alng a set of at most E directed paths from s to t.

Kindly request to help me in understand above theorem and corollaries with an simple example 
Thanks!

Comment: Please use a spellchecker or proof read your posts. Also, could you reformat your diagram? I bet it looks nothing like you intended.

Comment: Actually my question is that understand flow decompostion theorm and its corollary with simple graph example with cycles and path between s and t.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to other explanations of the (parts of) the algorithm you are having trouble with study those.  If that doesn't appeal to you start writing code.  I generally find that implementing an algorithm greatly improves my understanding of a description of the algorithm.

Actually, I disagree with the 2nd sentence in the previous paragraph -- whether further study appeals or not, start writing code.  I doubt that anyone can properly understand an algorithm without coding it.  Get off the sidelines, get into the game.

Comment: sorry it didn't answer my question.